# pgfplots with nonlinearly scaled color maps

Tags: pgfplots

This here is a question which came on the pgfplots mailing list; I answer it here since this allows an answer of higher quality.

---

I have a picture that uses a diverging color map.

In this case, minimum and maximum don’t have the same absolute value (but -0.2 and +0.5 instead)

I want to be able to do a "centered color map", where “0” is the middle color, all points >0 use the upper half of the map, and all <0 the lower half.

The color bar should be skewed according to the real values (i.e. the lower half of the map should take up 2/7 of the bar,a nd the upper half the remaining 5/7)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} 


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    % I want the color to be distributed in a nonlinear way, not like this
    % I want the tick labels to reflect the centered colorbar
    colorbar,
]
    \addplot[line width=3pt,mesh,domain=-0.2:0.5] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

maybe a point meta center=[auto,] key, with auto meaning a calculated value of (point meta max + point meta min) ÷ 2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to scale the `point meta`. Naturally, this will also scale the `colorbar` and its axis descriptions. But since a `colorbar` is actually nothing but a normal `axis`, we can defined custom transformations to "undo" the effect.

The following code defines a new style `nonlinear colormap around 0={<min>}{<max>}` which rescales the point meta (assuming that it would have been the `y` coordinate by default). It also rescales the colorbar in a non-linear way to restore the correct descriptions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} 

\pgfplotsset{
    % this transformation ensures that every input argument is
    % transformed from -0.2 : 0.5 -> -0.5,0.5 
    % and every tick label is transformed back:
    nonlinear colormap trafo/.code 2 args={
        \def\nonlinearscalefactor{((#2)/(#1))}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            y coord trafo/.code={%
                \pgfmathparse{##1 < 0 ? -1*##1*\nonlinearscalefactor : ##1}%
            },
            y coord inv trafo/.code={%
                \pgfmathparse{##1 < 0 ? -1*##1/\nonlinearscalefactor : ##1}%
            },
        }%
    },
    nonlinear colormap around 0/.code 2 args={
        \def\nonlinearscalefactor{((#2)/(#1))}%
        \pgfkeysalso{
            colorbar style={
                nonlinear colormap trafo={#1}{#2},
                %
                % OVERRIDE this here. The value is *only* used to
                % generate a nice axis, it does not affect the data.
                % Note that these values will be mapped through the
                % colormap trafo as defined above.
                point meta min={#1},
                point meta max={#2},
            },
            %
            % this here is how point meta is computed for the plot.
            % It means that a point meta of -0.2 will actually become -0.5
            % Thus, the *real* point meta min is -0.5... but we
            % override it above.
            point meta={y < 0 ? -y*\nonlinearscalefactor : y},
        }%
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    colorbar,
    %
    % activate the nonlinear colormap:
    nonlinear colormap around 0={-0.2}{0.5},
    %
    % reconfigure it - the default yticks are typically unsuitable
    % (because they are chosen in a linear way)
    colorbar style={
        ytick={-0.2,-0.1,0,0.25,0.5},
    },
]
    \addplot[line width=3pt,mesh,domain=-0.2:0.5] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```