# Nonlinear color maps in surf plots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following plot

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain = -20:30,
    y domain = 0.01:100,
    ymode=log,
    view = {0}{90},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    colorbar
    ]

    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp, samples=41]%
    {-1 + (y * sqrt(1+x^2))^2) / (1+y)^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following
[image: MWE output]

However, I would like the colormap to be equally divided between [0,1] and [1, 1000]. Or possibly two different colormaps for the two ranges. How can I achieve this? I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166776/pgfplots-with-nonlinearly-scaled-color-maps) but this solution does not change the colormapping, just the colorbar.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23750/log-color-bar-meta-data-in-pgfplot?rq=1) could help? It seems to address a very similar issue.

Comment: I do not understand your statement about [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166776/pgfplots-with-nonlinearly-scaled-color-maps). Isn't the only difference that you need to distinguish `<1` and `>1` instead of `<0` and `>0`?

Comment: @marmot, I think I would also need to subtract 1 from y. In any case, if I use this solution the figure would not change, only the colorbar, i.e., the blue region would stay blue. The post by @Ϛ seems more to the point, although I would like more control than just logarithmic scaling, if that's possible with pgfplots.

Comment: @Tohiko Sure. My statement is just to express that I am not convinced that "but this solution does not change the colormapping, just the colorbar." is correct.