# general question about custom colormaps

Tags: pgfplots, color

I am wondering if there is the possibility in `pgfplots` to define a color according to the value of the data, which should be plotted?

What I am thinking of is to define individual colors for all `values < 0` and `values > 0` and white for `values = 0` and then combine these colors in a `colormap`.

Hopefully, one can understand what I am talking about. I can also think of a MWE, but right now I just whant to know if it is actually possible and if yes, how to proceed.

**Edit**

To clarify my problem, I had a look at related questions and found [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571436/cyclic-colormap-in-pgfplots-for-surface-2d-phase-plots) and may add a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{
    colormap/corr2Dplus/.style={colormap={corr2Dplus}{
            rgb255=(255,255,255);
            rgb255=(255,255,0);
            rgb255=(255,0,0);
            rgb255=(102,0,0);
        }
    },
    colormap/corr2Dminus/.style={colormap={corr2Dminus}{
            rgb255=(255,255,255);
            rgb255=(0,255,255);
            rgb255=(0,0,255);
            rgb255=(0,0,102);
        }
    },
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.txt}
    x y z
    0 0 0
    0 1 0
    1 0 1
    1 1 1
    2 0 2
    2 1 2
    3 0 3 
    3 1 3
    4 0 -3
    4 1 -3 
    5 0 -2
    5 1 -2
    6 0 -1
    6 1 -1
    7 0  0
    7 1  0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\zlim{3}% <- later, I calculate this value automatically
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{90},
            colormap/corr2Dplus,
            colorbar,
            title=positive values,
            ]
            
            \addplot3[
                mesh/rows=8,
                surf,  
                colormap/corr2Dplus,
                shader=interp,
            ]
            table[
                z expr={\thisrow{z} > 0},
            ] from {data.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{90},
                colormap/corr2Dminus,
                colorbar,
                title=negative values,
            ]
            
            \addplot3[
                mesh/rows=8,
                surf,  
                colormap/corr2Dminus,
                shader=interp,   
            ] 
            table[
                z expr={\thisrow{z} < 0}
            ] from {data.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{90},
            colormap/corr2Dminus,
            colorbar,
            title=negative values,
            ]
            
            \addplot3[
            mesh/rows=8,
            surf,  
            colormap/corr2Dminus,
            shader=interp,   
            ] 
            table[
            z expr={\thisrow{z} < 0}
            ] from {data.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, my question is: **How can I combine the two pictures into one?**

[image]

Comment: Do you have one single value per color (1=red,2=purple,3=orange etc) or can there be continuous values in between (for example 1.432145 that should be mapped to red and 1.6086 that should be mapped to purple)?

Comment: And are the minimum and maximum values known and fixed?

Comment: As Marijn already mentioned, it is not totally clear how you want to define colors and the `colormap` respectively. Thus, maybe you first have a look at the corresponding [section in the PGFPlots manual](https://ftp.mpi-inf.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#subsection.4.7.6) to see how `colormap`s can be defined and how colors can be accessed.

Comment: @Marijn @ Stefan Pinnow Thanks for your remarks. I added a MWE for more clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply combining the `colormap`s seems to work ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        colormap={corr2D}{
            rgb255=(0,0,102);
            rgb255=(0,0,255);
            rgb255=(0,255,255);
            rgb255=(255,255,255);
            rgb255=(255,255,0);
            rgb255=(255,0,0);
            rgb255=(102,0,0);
        },
    }
    \begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.txt}
        x y z
        0 0 0
        0 1 0
        1 0 1
        1 1 1
        2 0 2
        2 1 2
        3 0 3
        3 1 3
        4 0 -3
        4 1 -3
        5 0 -2
        5 1 -2
        6 0 -1
        6 1 -1
        7 0  0
        7 1  0
    \end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{90},
            colormap name=corr2D,
            colorbar,
        ]
            \addplot3[
                mesh/rows=8,
                surf,
                shader=interp,
            ] table {data.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: @ Stefan Pinnow That was my starting point. Originally, I was asking this question, because I had some strange signals in my graph. Right now, I figured out the 'error' by myself, but I add the MWE here for more clarity.

Comment: Hopefully you agree that this is a totally different question that you have now. I therefore suggest that we revert it to a previous edit and that you ask a new question with your *real* problem.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Since I first found no solution for my problem, I was thinking of an alternative way to achieve my goal. Luckily, I found an easy solution.

Comment: Great. As said above I reverted the edits to the original question.